# BASH SCRIPT output doesn't export in file

Tags: bash, sockets, curl, websocket, ws

i just stuck with my self coded application calling ws command (web socket) and i'm trying to export the output. Also i want to exit wscat when it's finished after sometime of input from API from the JSON backend devlopment

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts a:c: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        a) accesskey=${OPTARG};;
    c) clientnodeid=${OPTARG};;     
    esac
done
master="wscat -c ws://localhost:8091/ws/callback -H accessKey:$accesskey -H clientNodeId:$clientnodeid"
sleep 15
eval $master
final=$(eval echo "$master")
echo $final >>logfile.log
ps -ef | grep wscat | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
#curl -X POST --data "$final" -k "https://localhost:7460/activate" -H "accept: application/json" -H "accessKey:$accesskey" -H "clientNodeId:$clientnodeid" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "callbackRequested:true"
exit
```

I want to call then output from wscat to sent over curl
When i run the script manually it got success but when i call it from another application (java) it's it running but not generating log.

With all words, i want to export $final to text file and that text file i should import it to --data of curl calling

Comment: Btw.: You could replace `ps -ef | grep wscat | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill` with `pkill wscat`.

Comment: Add full path to `logfile.log`?

Comment: Thanks! Do you have some comments why it cannot generate fully output from the master= variable ?

I have tried both....when i run manually it saving to the /root directory, doesn't that matter?

Comment: `final=$(eval echo "$master")` is the same as just `final=$master`. It doesn't execute `wscat` because of `echo`.

Comment: If you want to capture the output of `wscat`, use `final=$(eval "$master")`

Comment: Unless you put `wscat` into the background with `&`, you won't get past the line that executes it until it exits. So there's no need to kill it.

Comment: You're overcomplicating this with all those variables. Just do `eval "$master" >> logfile.log`

Comment: Thanks @Barmar that worked, but i want now to wait a for 15 seconds then export it to log file eval "$master" && sleep 15 >> logfile.log

Should be that command?

Comment: `eval "$master" | (sleep 15; cat >> logfile.log)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed based on [@Barmar's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70103990/bash-script-output-doesnt-export-in-file/70113410#comment123925754_70103990):

> You're overcomplicating this with all those variables. Just do
>
> ```
> eval "$master" >> logfile.log
> ```